# Displaying 2 images on same window using winapi

Tags: c++, winapi, bitmap

I would like to display 2 images on the same window using Winapi calls like `bitblr` or `stretchblt`. How can I achieve this? I'm using the following code:

```
hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);
bmpExercising1 = LoadBitmap(GetModuleHandle(NULL),IDB_FILE1);
bmpExercising2 = LoadBitmap(GetModuleHandle(NULL),IDB_FILE2);
// Create a memory device compatible with the above DC variable
MemDCExercising1 = CreateCompatibleDC(hdc);
MemDCExercising2 = CreateCompatibleDC(hdc);
// Select the new bitmap
SelectObject(MemDCExercising1, bmpExercising1);
SelectObject(MemDCExercising1, bmpExercising1);

// suppose the size of window is 80*80 then
StretchBlt(hdc, 0, 0, 40, 40, MemDCExercising1, 0, 0,bmpExercising1.width,bmpExercising1,height, SRCCOPY);
StretchBlt(hdc, 40, 40, 80, 80, MemDCExercising2, 0, 0,bmpExercising2.width,bmpExercising2,height, SRCCOPY);

EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
```

Comment: Looks like a typo. You did not select anything into MemDCExercising2

Comment: You are selecting first bitmap twice, yet there is nothing in your second memory DC. As others stated, it looks like your problem is copy/paste typo. Change your second `SelectObject(MemDCExercising1, bmpExercising1);` into `SelectObject(MemDCExercising2, bmpExercising2);` and tell us what you get then.